# Duplicate class while adding admob sdk in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, admob

when i am trying to add dependency `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.8.0'`

on my android studio project

it shows a list of errors

```
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zza found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.8.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.6.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.6.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzb found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.8.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.6.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.6.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzc found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.8.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.6.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.6.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzd found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.8.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.6.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.6.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.zza found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.8.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.6.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.6.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzb found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.8.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.6.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.6.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzab found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.8.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.6.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.6.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.8.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.6.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.6.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzad found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.8.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.6.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.6.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzae found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.8.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.6.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.6.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaf found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.8.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.6.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.6.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzb found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.8.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.6.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.6.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzr found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.8.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.6.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.6.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzs found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.8.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.6.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.6.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzt found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.8.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.6.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.6.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzu found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.8.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.6.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.6.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzv found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.8.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.6.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.6.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzw found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.8.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.6.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.6.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzx found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.8.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.6.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.6.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzy found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.8.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.6.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.6.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.zze found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.8.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.6.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.6.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.8.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.6.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.6.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zzb found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.8.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.6.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.6.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

how can I fix it

and my dependencies here

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement Ads in your project, It will be done with;

> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.1.0'

Just remove this;

> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.8.0'

Comment: but also i  need this  `com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.8.0` because the application is using QRCode detection service

Comment: by the way problem is solved by changing the version of  `com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision` `11.8.0` to `20.1.3`